How can i Get a JSON structure response from the google gemini-pro-vision
google gemini_response is string I need in the JSON Structure like this
{
"Title": "chair",
"Description": "A wooden chair with wheels",
"Category": "Furniture",
"Subcategory": "office stuff",
"EstimatedPrice": "$10 - 20 "
}
I try the json_laod() to desearlize but my reponse is not like JSON! How can i do this into a proper JSON ?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your situation. But, in this case, how about using the property responseMimeType? Ref If my guess of your situation was not correct, I apologize.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

JSON Mode has recently been introduced in the Gemini API for the Gemini 1.5 Pro and Gemini 1.5 Flash models (sadly not available in the Gemini 1.0 Pro Vision model that you're using).
But both models support image input, just like the pro vision model, as documented here.
Using the Gemini 1.5 Flash model
This model is somewhat limited when it comes to schema - you have to pass it as part of your prompt, for example:
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash',
                              generation_config={"response_mime_type": "application/json"})

prompt = 'List 5 office supplies for my e-commerce website, with this schema: { "Title": str, "Description": str, "Category": str, "Subcategory": str, "EstimatedPrice": str}'

response = model.generate_content(prompt)
print(response.text)

Using the Gemini 1.5 Pro model
If you're using the Gemini 1.5 Pro model, You can create a Python class to serve as schema and pass it as response_schema:
import typing_extensions as typing

# Define your schema
class Product(typing.TypedDict)
  title: str
  description: str
  category: str
  subcategory: str
  estimatedPrice: str

# Call the API
model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="models/gemini-1.5-pro")

result = model.generate_content(
  "List 5 office supplies for my e-commerce website",
  generation_config=genai.GenerationConfig(response_mime_type="application/json",
                                           response_schema = list[Product]))

print(result.text)

Which model should I use ?
I think that depends on what you're looking for. The differences between the models are listed in the docs and they also come at different prices.

can you clarify if Gemini has official JSON Schema support and which draft versions are supported or just JSON with a pseudo-schema?

@JeremyFiel I couldn't find any documentation around that, but it seems like another Gemini feature (Function Calling) uses OpenAPI Schema 3.0.3 as documented here and I assume JSON Mode uses that same version.
But from my own testing, it seems like I can pass any pseudo-schema to the model and it still understands, so I don't think there is a strict validator there.

Can I recommend you contact a google colleague to update the marketing text to remove the reference to JSON schema or to clarify Gemini does not officially support JSON Schema.

@JeremyFiel I filed a bug internally, thanks for the feedback!
(I'm leaving the id here for future reference and for any other Googler who sees this: b/343965971)

Looks like it's returning JSON by default? https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/gemini#response
However, see
JSON format responses

Depending on your application, you may want the response to a prompt
to be returned in a structured data format, particularly if you are
using the responses to populate programming interfaces. The Gemini API
provides a configuration parameter to request a response in JSON
format.
Note: This response configuration option is supported only with the
Gemini 1.5 Pro and 1.5 Flash models.

Basically add this to a HTTP POST body to get JSON:
      "generationConfig": {
            "response_mime_type": "application/json",
      }

